Next.js 14: Framer Motion useScroll with element container not updating
I'm using Next.js v14.2.5 and Framer Motion v11.3.21. I'm working on a card carousel that scrolls horizontally. To track the scrolling progress, I'm using the useScroll hook from Framer Motion. However, I'm facing an issue where the useScroll hook is not detecting the scrolling or updating the scrolling value correctly.
Heres my code
'use client'
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useScroll, useTransform, motion, useMotionValueEvent } from "framer-motion";

export default function Home() {
  const carouselRef = useRef(null);
  const [progress, setPorgress] = useState(0);

  const { scrollXProgress } = useScroll({
    container: carouselRef
  });
  const background = useTransform(scrollXProgress, [0, 1], ['rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'rgb(220, 0, 0)']);
  
  return (
    <motion.main className='h-full flex items-center overflow-x-scroll snap-x snap-mandatory' style={{ background }}>
      <div ref={carouselRef} className='flex gap-4'>
        <div className='bg-red-500 h-96 rounded-md w-[calc(100vw_-_2rem)] mx-4 p-4 text-white snap-center shadow-lg'>
          <h1>Card</h1>
          { progress }
         </div>
        <div className='bg-blue-500 h-96 rounded-md w-[calc(100vw_-_2rem)] mx-4 p-4 text-white snap-center shadow-lg'>
          <h1>Card</h1>
        </div>
        <div className='bg-green-500 h-96 rounded-md w-[calc(100vw_-_2rem)] mx-4 p-4 text-white snap-center shadow-lg'>
          <h1>Card</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </motion.main>
  );
}

Im using useTrasform in order to see the change in scrolling progress visually, but instead the progress values seems to be always equal to 1
How can I track the scrolling progress value correctly ?

I don't think you need your own progress state. The progress should be scrollXProgress. Here is an example from framer https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-usescroll-element-scrolling-eg6fm3?from-embed
